# Example code from "Real World Ocaml" doesn't run as intended.

Tags: ocaml

I'm learning ocaml so it's maybe trivial.

When I try to build executable of this code:

```
open Core.Std

let build_counts () =
  In_channel.fold_lines stdin ~init:[] ~f:(fun counts line ->
    let count =
      match List.Assoc.find counts line with
      | None -> 0
      | Some x -> x
    in
    List.Assoc.add counts line (count + 1)
  )

let () =
  build_counts ()
  |> List.sort ~cmp:(fun (_,x) (_,y) -> Int.descending x y)
  |> (fun l -> List.take l 10)
  |> List.iter ~f:(fun (line,count) -> printf "%3d: %s\n" count line)
```

I get this error:

> Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a option
>          but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
>            equal:(Stdio__.Import.string -> Stdio__.Import.string -> bool) ->
>            'b option

Where is the problem?

Link: https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/files-modules-and-programs.html

Comment: Strange, it works for me without any changes

Comment: Might depend on your version of `core`. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the type signature for `List.Assoc.find`:

```
('a, 'b) Base__List.Assoc.t -> equal:('a -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a -> 'b option
```

The first argument is the associative list (`counts` in the example). The last argument (of type `'a`) is the key you're looking for (this is `line` in your example). There is another argument, however, of type `'a -> 'a -> bool` which labeled `equal`. It's pretty straight-forward that it is a comparison function used by `List.Assoc.find` to see whether two keys are equals.

In the case where `'a` is `string`, a simple `(=)` is enough. You can fix your code by replacing your `match` line with the following:

```
match List.Assoc.find counts ~equal:(=) line with
```

The `List.Assoc.add` function follows the same pattern. You should replace the last line of the `build_counts` function with the following:

```
List.Assoc.add counts ~equal:(=) line (count + 1)
```

---

As a side-note, Real World OCaml is getting quite old (this is why some examples are outdated), and the authors are working on a second edition.